# How to repair a leaking dishwasher

Tags: appliances, dishwasher

We have a rental apartment and the dishwasher is leaking from the front - Amana, not sure which model.

There appears to be a crack in the interior base of the machine. Our landlord attempted to seal it with liquid silicone, but the heating unit caused it to melt.  He has also tried Flex Tape on the exterior, but it does not seem to have helped either.

Beyond replacing the unit, is there any way we could repair this dishwasher so it does not leak?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without determining exactly where the leak is coming from -- loose seal, cracked component, something else. Doesn't sound like either you or the landlord have determined that yet... ?

Comment: I imagine it is made out of plastic, so you can try plastic welding or an epoxy adhesive for a longer lasting repair.  Plastic welding(google it) should be the best choice.

Comment: Sounds like a problem for the landlord to me.  If the LL digs in his heels, I'd just get a used dishwasher off CL or FBM.  Sell it on the same when you move out, and probably make (most of) your money back.

Comment: Depending on where in the world you are, there might be recourse for sub-standard rental conditions. Admittedly, ratcheting up the pressure on the landlord will probably get you thrown out, which is a consideration.

Comment: I wouldn't try to repair a dishwasher tub. That's a low success scenario. There's too much thermal change and movement for it to be reliable. It needs replacement.

Comment: @Huesmann His real problem is he always insists on doing his own repairs - no matter  what.

Comment: @Zibbobz nothing wrong with that if he gets it done in a timely and complete fashion.

Comment: @Huesmann That is the trouble isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

Take pics of the area and document that you have logged notification with the landlord.

**Then don't touch it.**

Once you do, you own it and the landlord can claim that you made things worse and now it cannot be repaired.

Give the landlord reminders that you continue to have issues and take more pics if there is water on the floor or getting on the cabinets.
Do clean up any water as best you can. That is your responsibility.

If after a reasonable time,  ( Usually 30-45 days) The landlord has not properly repaired the problem and you can document that period you can push harder.  That could be with letters from community advocates or your local housing authority. Often they have volunteer legal assistance to help renters get the action they need.  You can try going to court, but things rarely get that far.  You can threaten to move, but that could very well backfire and put you in a position to lose your security deposit.

The best course is to keep reminding the landlord that there is an issue.  Be reasonable and appeal to his senses by communication that you are interested in making sure the issue does not cause more damage to his unit.  This make you out to be the responsible party and does not put the landlord on the defensive.
With a bit of common sense the landlord will see how it is advantageous to him to correct the problem soon.

Good luck.

Comment: It may be hard to argue that not having a dishwasher is a serious enough problem to be legally actionable, unless you can show that the rental unit was advertised as having one or it's on the lease. But definitely don't do anything permanent to it without landlord's permission or you may find your security deposit dinged for it